# Why onNext of Subject is unsolved?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject, subject-observer

In Angular2. When I call onNext on a Subject, it shows unsolved. rx is correctly imported.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
...
private _subject = new Subject();

...
this._progress$ = Observable.create(observer => {
      this._progressObserver = observer
    }).share();
    this._subject = Subject.create(this._progressObserver, this._progress$);

...
this._subject.onNext(10/100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `.next()`. not `onNext()`

```
this._subject.next(10/100);
```

Comment: Gunter, I check the api online for https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md, and the observable,observer it inherits from,  https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md and https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observer.md. I did not find next()?

Comment: This is for RxJS 4, Angular uses 5 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#observer-interface-changes-also-subjects